# Databricks Spark Streaming Stops without any error message

Tags: pyspark, databricks, spark-streaming

The Streaming of data to the lake stops after writing to the lake with the messsage:

```
Streaming stopped
Out[18]: <pyspark.sql.streaming.StreamingQuery at 0x7eff3b40d8b0>
```

When I execute the cell with code it streams without any problems, but when the code is executed as part of a notebook run it fails with the above message.

The message doesn't indicate there is a problem, so I don't know what could cause the stream to stop with the message.

Any thoughts on what could be read from the message?

I forgot to add the code that is causing the stream to stop, see below:

```
(df.writeStream
    .format("delta")
    .foreachBatch(upsertToDelta)
    .outputMode("update")
    .option("checkpointLocation", f"{location}/_checkpoints")
    .start())
```